# How to know who added/edited the lines which are right now deleted/moved in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

For example, these lines are deleted from the class foobar.java

```
int foo = 1;
String bar = "two";
```

I can see that someone deleted these lines and that is around 1 year ago. But, now I wanted to know who originally added/edited these lines before. Right now, I am working on a file which is changed a lot in the last 2 years and I only know to go through the Perforce File History which is really tiresome and has a lot of history. I think it is really difficult to go through each changelist and determine who edited/added these lines. Does anyone know any tricks/tools inside perforce?

Answer (score 1):

Use `p4 annotate -a`.

```
    p4 annotate [-aciIqtTu -d<flags>] file[revRange] ...

        Prints all lines of the specified files, indicating the revision that
        introduced each line into the file.

        ...

        The -a flag includes both deleted files and lines no longer present
        at the head revision. In the latter case, both the starting and ending
        revision for each line is displayed.

        ...
```

Without the `-a` flag, `p4 annotate` shows you the revision in which each line in the given file revision was added:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 annotate foobar.java
//stream/main/foobar.java#3 - edit change 311 (text)
1: this is a sample file
2:
3: now there's some other stuff in here
```

With the `-a` flag, all of the deleted lines are shown as well, and each line is displayed with a range that shows what revisions it was present in:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 annotate -a foobar.java
//stream/main/foobar.java#3 - edit change 311 (text)
1-3: this is a sample file
2-3:
2-2: int foo = 1;
2-2: String bar = "two";
3-3: now there's some other stuff in here
```

The `2-2` lines were added in revision #2, and then deleted in revision #3.

You can take the revision numbers and correlate them to the history in `p4 filelog` to see which user created each revision and in which changelist and when:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 filelog foobar.java
//stream/main/foobar.java
... #3 change 311 edit on 2022/08/25 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'another edit'
... #2 change 310 edit on 2022/08/25 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'edit foobar'
... #1 change 309 add on 2022/08/25 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'add foobar'
```

or you can pass additional flags to `p4 annotate` to put some of that information right in the annotate output:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 annotate -atu foobar.java
//stream/main/foobar.java#3 - edit change 311 (text)
1-3: Samwise 2022/08/25 this is a sample file
2-3: Samwise 2022/08/25
2-2: Samwise 2022/08/25 int foo = 1;
2-2: Samwise 2022/08/25 String bar = "two";
3-3: Samwise 2022/08/25 now there's some other stuff in here
```

In P4V, you can use the "Time-Lapse View" feature to see the same information.